# In itext7, is there a way to prevent the bounding box being lost when copying pages using copyAsFormXObject method?

Tags: itext7

I have a landscape PDF (792x612) that has pages with a xObject containing a bounding box of 612x792. When copying the pages with itext7 the top of the pages are being clipped.

Example Code:

```
PdfFormXObject pageCopy = readerDocument.getPage(i).copyAsFormXObject(pDFDocument);
canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);
```

If I get the Bounding box of the pageCopy, it is set to the media box of the page. Example:

```
Rectangle bbSize = pageCopy.getBBox().toRectangle();
```

The size of the Rectangle is 792x612 instead of the expected value of 612x792.

In the PDF the Bounding box is clearly set to 612x792:

```
</Filter /FlateDecode/Length 842/Type /XObject/Subtype /Form/FormType 1/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/BBox [0 0 612 792]/Resources <</ExtGState <</Xi11 102 0 R>>/Font <</Xi10 103 0 R>>>>>>
```

If the page is copied with the PdfPage copyTo method no clipping occurs by the way. But this mean the page can not be resized if needed.

Comment: Hi, could you attach the pdf to the question? This will help us to know what your issue is faster. In any case, what you are doing is you copying a page, transforming it into an XObject. The page was 792x612, and the corresponding XObject is also 792x612. Why would it be different? Please clarify your question.

Comment: The xObject is 612x792 (/BBox [0 0 612 792]) but the media box is 792x612 (MediaBox [0 0 792 612]).

Comment: Do you happen to have CropBox in your page? Or is only MediaBox defined?

Comment: No cropbox, just a Mediabox